# How to set relative display size in Windows 10?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, mouse, window

I'm currently configuring my displays in Windows 10. I have a central monitor which is bigger and runs at a higher resolution than the two surrounding monitors. As such, whenever I move my mouse between the displays, my mouse jumps all over the place due to the height difference. How can I set it up so that the top and the bottom of the displays are the same, no matter the actual size or resolution of my display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Windows 10 is currently not supporting relative display size scaling. The displays scale according to their resolution, not their actual size, so one needs to approximate their position in the virtual space.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on desktop.

Click display settings.

Drag around the boxes that represent the screens at the top of the box to achive the desired orientation.

Click apply.

???.

Profit.

Comment: That only changes where the mouse cursor enters / leaves, not the size of the boxes. If I could resize them to be the same size, that would probably work, but no luck there...